# Why does MYSQL identify the column as the table?

Tags: mysql

The respective table and my respective query looks like this (see image):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHJn5.jpg
(Although in the screenshot my query contained "arbeitplatz", I immediately afterwards changed it to the correct "arbeitsplatz". The behavior didnt change though, same Error as seen on the screenshot)

I don't understand why MYSQL behaves like this. ID is a column, I also referred to it as such. The table is arbeitsplatz. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to ask... read over DELETE syntax again.. you can't delete a column....

Comment: I believe your query is wrong: the correct format seems to be "DELETE FROM table_name [WHERE Clause]" (so nothing needs to be put between "DELETE" and "FROM"). You are trying to remove tuples from a table, not columns, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `DELETE` syntax you used is wrong.
The right one is

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

Also see documntation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html.